# How can I eject a disc from the Xbox One remotely?

Tags: xbox-one

So, on the Xbox 360 (and on pretty much every physical media player that has a remote control) I can remotely eject the disc from the console while I'm sitting on my sofa, and then by the time I step across to the console, it's already sticking out waiting for me.

There are multiple options to do this on the 360, either highlighting the default top-left tile and pressing <kbd>Y</kbd>, or pressing the "Open/Close" button on my Xbox Media Remote, or [using Kinect](http://support.xbox.com/xbox-360/kinect/control-your-xbox-360-with-your-voice) I could say "Xbox Open Tray".

None of these methods seem to work on the Xbox One, I can't find any way to do it with the controller (I have tried selecting the disc tile in the bottom right and pressing the controller's menu button, but there's nothing relevant on there), there is no media remote, and nothing like that is listed in the [new Kinect Voice Commands list](http://support.xbox.com/xbox-one/kinect/voice-commands).

Do I really have to stand up, walk across the room, and press the Eject button on the front of the console? Even my '80s VCR let me eject tapes from the sofa!

---

Edit: If you're interested in this, here are some requests on the [Xbox User Voice](http://xbox.uservoice.com) site to vote on or keep an eye on:

- [Ability to eject the disc that is in tray using Kinect by saying "Xbox eject"](http://xbox.uservoice.com/forums/251617-kinect/suggestions/6029001-ability-to-eject-the-disc-that-is-in-tray-using-ki).
- [Disc eject using controller on Xbox One](http://xbox.uservoice.com/forums/253802-home-settings/suggestions/6030803-disc-eject-using-controller-on-xbox-one)
- [Be able to eject the disc with the Y button](http://xbox.uservoice.com/forums/251646-apps/suggestions/6325893-be-able-to-eject-the-disc-with-the-y-button)
- [Eject button in smartglass](http://xbox.uservoice.com/forums/251651-smartglass/suggestions/6036634-eject-button-in-smartglass)

Comment: The tag first-world-problems seems applicable here.

Comment: @adriano isn't this whole site one big collection of first world problems? ;)

Comment: well, there are some more so than others.

Comment: I've never understood this. You still have to walk over to the console to put the disc away anyway, why not just press the button while you're there?

Comment: I'd argue the inverse, you need this feature to have a way to make a disc go BACK into the console remotely. My cat walks by the xbox and swishes her tail against the front, and DING there goes the disc. Now I have to get up and put the damn disc back in its case (which i don't want to do, it makes no sense if you don't switch games often), or just put the damn disc back in the console (which, annoyingly, starts the game up). And not ten seconds later the cat's like "Oh whoops sorry about that but you're up now? Look how cute I can be DING oh whoops DING whats that DING"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I couldn't find anything about this, so I [asked @XboxSupport](https://twitter.com/XboxSupport3/status/405137298515173376). Sounds like the only way to eject the disc is with the button currently:

> @schottac The eject button on the console is the best bet! ^LL

Comment: Thanks for going that extra mile, accepting this as the correct answer. (but I'm crossing fingers hoping some future software update may bring this back)

Comment: @GAThrawn Me too - additional voice commands seems like something that could be added in a patch later, so here's hoping.

Answer (score -2):

I do not think there is a voice command. The tiny yellow tab mentioned in another answer will not solve anything, as it is even more manual than pushing the button.